# String dentro de lista Python

Tags: python

Tenho `string` em Python armazenada em uma variável e eu quero verificar se ela existe dentro de uma lista.

Usei o `in` para isso mais mesmo com a saída igual ao que esta na lista ele nao me retorna corretamente

O que eu tentei:

```
EAN = 7896000111371
quantidade = 1
quantidade = EAN,quantidade
        print(quantidade)
        if quantidade in lista :
            print(f"quantidade confere: {quantidade}")
            print("#------------------------------#")
        else:
            print(f"Quantidade INVALIDO: {quantidade}")
            print("#------------------------------#")
```

Saída:

> ```
> EAN encontrado: 7896000111371
> ('7896000111371', '1')
> Quantidade INVALIDO: ('7896000111371', '1')
> ```

Lista:

```
[['7890000103404', '1'], ['7896000100634', '2'], ['7896000111371', '1'], ['7896000104335', '2'], ['7896000111364', '1'], ['7890000101059', '2'], ['7890000100724', '1'], ['7896000100870', '1'], ['7890000100472', '2'], ['7890000101943', '2'], ['7896000108869', '1'], ['7896000108852', '1'], ['7896000101679', '1'], ['7890000100816', '1'], ['7896000109040', '1'], ['7896000102324', '1'], ['7890000101219', '1'], ['7896000102768', '1'], ['7890000100687', '1'], ['7896000106322', '1']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está criando uma tupla no momento que faz

```
quantidade = EAN, quantidade
```

Porém, você está comparando com uma lista de listas. Ou seja, cada elemento da sua lista é uma outra lista com dois elementos.

Além disso, os elementos das listas internas são *strings* e a tupla que você está criando contém números inteiros, este caso é mais fácil de resolver, você apenas precisa criar a lista (ou tupla) usando os elementos como strings.

Você pode solucionar o problema criando uma lista ao invés de uma tupla

```
lista = [['7890000103404', '1'], ['7896000111371', '1']]
quantidade = ['7896000111371', '1'] # Note o uso das aspas aqui
    
if quantidade in lista :
    print(f"quantidade confere: {quantidade}")
    print("#------------------------------#")
else:
    print(f"Quantidade INVALIDO: {quantidade}")
    print("#------------------------------#")
```

Ou então adaptar a lista para que os itens sejam tuplas

```
lista = [('7890000103404', '1'), ('7896000111371', '1')]
quantidade = '7896000111371', '1'
    
if quantidade in lista :
    print(f"quantidade confere: {quantidade}")
    print("#------------------------------#")
else:
    print(f"Quantidade INVALIDO: {quantidade}")
    print("#------------------------------#")
```

[**Veja funcionando no Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso471324)

Answer (score 2):

O erro acontece por dois motivos:

1. Do jeito que a variável 'quantidade' foi declarada, ela forma uma tupla. Assim, o operador *in* só retornará verdadeiro se uma tupla com os elementos iguais aos da variável 'quantidade' estiver dentro da lista, o que é falso, já que a lista é formada por outras listas. Portanto, é necessário declarar a variável 'quantidade' como uma lista, usando colchetes, ou transformar as sublistas em tuplas;
2. Os elementos das sublistas que formam a variável lista, por terem sidos declarados com apóstrofo ('), são tratados como strings (ou caracteres, no caso do número). No entanto, os elementos da variável quantidade foram declaradas como inteiros. Isso faz com que o operador *in*, ao comparar a variável 'quantidade' com as sublistas da variável 'lista', obtenha falso como resposta. Portanto, ou os elementos das sublistas devem ser declarados como inteiros (removendo os apóstrofos) ou os elementos da variável 'quantidade' devem ser declarados como *strings* (adicionando os apóstrofos). Na solução abaixo, eu fiz da segundo forma.

O código corrigido fica da seguinte maneira:

```
lista = [['7890000103404', '1'], ['7896000100634', '2'], ['7896000111371', '1'], ['7896000104335', '2'], ['7896000111364', '1'], ['7890000101059', '2'], ['7890000100724', '1'], ['7896000100870', '1'], ['7890000100472', '2'], ['7890000101943', '2'], ['7896000108869', '1'], ['7896000108852', '1'], ['7896000101679', '1'], ['7890000100816', '1'], ['7896000109040', '1'], ['7896000102324', '1'], ['7890000101219', '1'], ['7896000102768', '1'], ['7890000100687', '1'], ['7896000106322', '1']]

EAN = '7890000103404'
quantidade = '1'
quantidade = [EAN,quantidade]

print(quantidade)

for item in lista:
    print(item)
    print(quantidade)

if quantidade in lista :
   print(f"quantidade confere: {quantidade}")
   print("#------------------------------#")
else:
   print(f"Quantidade INVALIDO: {quantidade}")
   print("#------------------------------#")
```

Comment: Boa resposta =)